# How do I get the "notes" files off my nokia phone?

Tags: windows-7, nokia-pc-suite, nokia-ovi-suite

I tend to write notes to myself as sms messages, but notes can be three times longer so that would be very handy, but I can't get them off the phone to copy and paste into documents I'm working on (there are a couple of programs from nokia which allow me to download text messages to my computer or read them and copy/paste).

I can send them between phones via Bluetooth, but I can't send them to my computer.

I have both of Nokia's PC programs installed, I can't find any way to access "notes" in PC suite. It seems I could sync notes in ovi if I had outlook installed, but I don't have outlook.

Surely they're stored on the phone somewhere? but when I look at the phone in Windows Explorer all I can access are the photos, videos, and sound files.

Comment: it seems i can send them to my computer but only one at a time, and i have to be near both my computer and my phone, which is too tedious.

Answer (score 3):

Except synchronizing them to Outlook you have two other choices:

1. Send them to the PC via Bluetooth one by one (as you already found out), or mark them and send all the marked ones once (on the PC side you will be asked where to save for every single one, but apart from the need to press OK multiple times, it's not that bad)
2. Backup the phone with PC Suite/Ovi Suite (only the Notes section), and then open the .nbu file generated by backup with [NbuExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbuexplorer/). You will be able to see them in the Memo section and do whatever you like with them (export to a file, copy/paste from them etc)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question till I managed to do it just now.

1. First you should download the backup `.nbu` file from your phone. For that you need a phone software. I used Nokia PC Suite (my phone is Nokia Xpress Music 5800). Save the `.nbu` file somewhere, say desktop.
2. You can access the contents of the backup with a program called [NBU Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbuexplorer/files/latest/download). Install and run the program (with your phone connected to the PC/laptop, of course.)
3. Open the phone backup file. All you have to do is click on the `Memo` menu item on the left pane, all your notes will appear on the right.

Comment: good job Jawa :)

Comment: What I especially like about this solution is that **note timestamps get preserved** when exporting them via rightclick and save them as txt files: they have their proper "Last modified" timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one trick for E72:

1. First go to Notes and Mark/Select all the notes that you want to export.
2. Click "Options" and select "Send".
3. Choose "Upload".
4. Answer "No" to the question to go online.
5. Connect your E72 to a PC with the cable and select "Mass storage".
6. Transfer the notes as txt files under "data" directory to your PC.

Comment: Great tip to backup notes without any additional software. However, I didn't manage to get a "No" dialog and find the txt files under data. Instead I used Send via Bluetooth which worked with my PC/laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that worked for me.

Select the notes you want to transfer, then choose Send->upload

Now on mine, this fails because ... reasons? But the notes are then copied to txt files on the SDCard, under E:\data\sharetemp

I then just copied them from there via whatever usual means. Use Y-browser to navigate files or just transfer with the PC suite phone browser.